# Trying to find Custom .htaccess for a static website

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect

I am creating a new static website. I have `folder1` and `folder2` which are folders on the remote web server. Each of these two folders may contain HTML files.

I want the following things to happen:

1. When he types www.domin.com/folder1/ -->display the index.html file under the folder1 folder
2. When he types www.domin.com/folder1 --> error
3. When he types www.domain.com/folder1/file1/ --> display the /folder1/file1.html file
4. When he types www.domain.com/folder/file.html or www.domain.com/folder/file  --> display an eror : such file does not exist

The only permitted URLs are:

- `domain.com/`
- `domain.com/about-file/`
- `domain.com/folder1/`
- `domain.com/folder1/file/`

The following solution does not work: when I types www.domain.com/folder/ or /folder/index.html it displays the doesnotexists.html for error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1/index.html [QSA,L]  # rule 1

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.html [QSA,L] # rule 3

RewriteRule ^[^/]+(/[^/]+(\.html)?)?$ doesnotexists.html [L] # rule 2 and 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if **/folder/index.html** or **/folder/** doesn't exist it SHOULD display 404.  Did you mean /folder**1**/index.html?  What does your ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log say about the accesses?  Are there also other errors?

Comment: the file doesnotexists.html is displayed instead. so I think there is an  error in the .htaccess rules